# NetLogo: Changing one breed's variable depending on other breed's variable in an ego-centric network environment

Tags: netlogo

Dear Stackoverflow users,

I am a newbie to NetLogo and the community here, so I hope I can express myself adequately. If you need more information in order to understand my question, please, let me know. As I am not completely sure, where my problem lies, my title might even be misleading.

*Here is what I am trying to do*: I want an ego-centric network model, in which 1 ego (a Latino immigrant in the US) starts with a given value (between 1 and 6) for

1. identification with Latino culture and
2. identification with US/White culture.

The ego (breed #1) has 8 alters (breed #2). The alters consist of Latinos and Whites (ratio to be determined by slider in the interface: number-Latinos). The alters are randomly connected between themselves (amount of undirected links to be determined by another slider in the interface: number-of-alter-links). Each alter has a value for degree d (which is the number of links within the same ethnicity).

At each tick, ego is supposed to interact randomly with one of the alters. If the alter is Latino, then ego's initial value for Latino identification should increase by 0.1 + d * 0.1. If the alter is White, ego's initial value for US identification should increase by 0.1 + d * 0.1. The maximum value that can be reached for the identification variables is 6.

*Here comes the code:*

```
breed [egos ego]
breed [alters alter]                                                     

egos-own[identification-US identification-Latino]
alters-own[degree]

 to setup
  clear-all
  setup-alters    
  setup-egos  
  reset-ticks
 end

to setup-alters
   create-alters 8 
   [layout-circle alters 8
     if who < number-Latinos [set color orange]        ; Latinos are orange
     if who >= number-Latinos [set color yellow]       ; Whites are yellow
     ]
   while [count links < number-of-alter-links][
     let node1 random 8
     let node2 random 8
     if (node1 != node2)[
       ask alter node1 [create-link-with alter node2]
     ]
     ]
   ask alters [                      ; set degree within same ethnicity
    ifelse color = yellow
    [set degree (count link-neighbors with [color = yellow])]
    [set degree (count link-neighbors with [color = orange])]
  ]
end

to setup-egos
   create-egos 1 [ 
    set identification-US initial-US-identification-ego
    set identification-Latino initial-Latino-identification-ego]
end

to go
  if ticks >= 50 [stop]
  interact
  change-identification
  tick
end

to interact
  ask egos [create-link-with one-of alters [set color green]]
end

to change-identification
  ask links with [color = green] [let d [degree] of end1
  ask egos [
  ifelse link-neighbors = yellow
    [ifelse (identification-US < 6)
      [set identification-US identification-US + 0.1 + d * 0.1]
      [set identification-US 6]
      ]
   [ifelse (identification-Latino < 6)
      [set identification-Latino identification-Latino + 0.1 + d * 0.1]
      [set identification-Latino 6]
      ]
   ]
  ]
  ask egos [ask my-links [die]] 
end
```

*This is my problem:* When I am running the simulation, only the value for Latino identification changes, but not the one for US identification. This is even true, when there are no Latinos in the network. I am not sure where the problem lies. Is it in the nested ifelse command? I have tried to work my way around the nested ifelse and made several if commands, but the problem remains. Does it have to do with how I defined the two ethnicities with colors? Also, when I ask in the command center something about a particular turtle (e.g., turtle 3), I get the answer 9 times (total number of turtles). Maybe the problem is how I ask the link-neighbor(s) for its color?

Thanks for your attention! Any idea, suggestion or possible solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This will always be false: `link-neighbors = yellow`.

Btw, if you post an entire model like this, you need to replace the interface globals with code-based declaration and initialization of the variables.

Comment: Thank you, Alan, for pointing me to the right direction and for the advice concerning the code-based declaration and initialization of the variables! I finally found a solution to the problem. I added a new variable called ethnicity storing the value for the color of the other end `let ethnicity [color] of end1`  and turned the ifelse command into two if commands `if ethnicity = yellow...`and `if ethnicity = orange...`